# Can I force a laptop to use a higher resolution?

Tags: laptop, resolution, high-resolution

I bought [my laptop](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0052D5BY0) (ASUS A53SV-XE1 15.6-Inch Versatile Entertainment Laptop) from amazon a few days ago, and when I got it today, I was so disappointed, the screen can't even compare with the laptop I bought at 2005. I think the main reason is the resolution is to low: 15.6-inch LED-backlit HD display with 1366 x 768.

This resolution is the same as my 13-inch laptop, I can see font edges pixels.

So my question is, can I force it use a higher resolution? it's already the max resolution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it's at the max resolution, then no, it can't go higher. Your best bet is to attach an external display and use that when you're not out on the go.

Comment: Best bet is to return it, I think ;)

Comment: @Yar Can I return it in this case?

Comment: It depends on the rules of who you bought it from. Some may require something to be wrong to return it. Others may allow returns for any reason so long as the system is not physically damaged.

Comment: If the OP (@Tony) bought it from Amazon, meaning amazon.com in the United States, yes.